# Microsoft purview - unable to approve a workflow request

Tags: azure, azure-purview

In `MS Purview`, after creating [Approval workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/how-to-workflow-business-terms-approval), the approver successfully gets an email request for an approval for creating a business glossary term, but when the approver goes to the Approval page of the Purview workflow, the response dropdown (shown in image 1 below) is disabled - and hence cannot select Approve or Reject option.

**Question**: What could be the cause of this issue (dropdown disabled) and how can we resolve it?

**Remarks**:

1. In our organization, we have two domains, one is for email, say, `EmailDomain.com` and another domain, say, `ITDomain.com` where `MS Purview` is installed. When you login to `MS Purview`, you have to use `ITDomain.com` (e.g. you login to Purview as `John.Smith@ITDomain.com`). But when you select an `approver` from a workflow screen (shown in image 2 below), you have to select approver's email address from email domain, for example, `Bob.Doe@EmailDomain.com`.
2. The approver is a global admin of Purview and is also Workflow Admin in Purview

[image]

**Image 2** [step 8 of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/how-to-workflow-business-terms-approval#create-and-enable-a-new-approval-workflow-for-business-terms) section]:
[image]